# Add a site column to the Folder Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, modern-experience, metadata

I am using SharePoint Online to store some files in a library. Inside that library, I have some sub-folders, and I created a column and enabled it for "All content types" as below:

[image]

The main goal is to define some metadata to that sub-folder based on the columns created in the library. When I go to the properties to that folder form I can't see the custom column that I created and I saw that the content type is "Folder":

[image]

I go to advanced settings of the library and enabled the content type but I discovered that the Document Type is set by default and when I tried to add the Folder Content type I was not able to find it.

[image]

I have also tried to add that custom column to the "Folder" Content-type but it's not reflecting in the library because I was not able to assign that type of content.

[image]

Can please someone provide an example with a screenshot of how to achieve the above scenario by adding a custom column to the Folder content and being able to define metadata to those folders?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge, you cannot add site column to out of the box Folder content type added to SharePoint document libraries.

However, you can add metadata to your folders/subfolders from **Grid view** like:

[image]

Comment: Hello Ganesh, I already tried that option but the problem is I have more than 80k files in the library, and when I try to select the folder that I want to add metadata for in the grid view sometimes it is not clickable and takes some time to able to define it.  I am sure this is can be done because if it is provided in the site content, not as read-only then we can add columns. any other alternative option?

Comment: There is no other way to add site column to *out of the box Folder content type added to SharePoint document libraries*. Another way >> You can create a custom content type (by setting Folder as parent content type) & add that content type to document library & use it instead of default folder content type (I suppose as you already have lot of folders/files, this will also not feasible for you).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried yesterday to add the custom column to the Item content type since it's the parent of the Folder and I published it. Now I just checked and discovered that the custom column that I created was added successfully to the Folder content. Please have a look https://imgur.com/o6E4tDL   https://imgur.com/P7MnqOS . Btw the default folder content is type is not found under the site content types in the library only the Document content is assigned

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. Yes, default folder content type is not shown on library settings that's why we cannot add custom column in that content type.

Comment: Now, as you added a custom column in default item content type, is this custom column showing in all child content types, lists, libraries as well?

Comment: Hey Ganesh, unfortunately, this custom column is showing in all lists and libraries so I think a custom folder content type should be created and assigned only to a specific library it will be the best solution what do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested earlier. Give it a try. When you add new custom content type in document library, will you disable OOTB folder option from library & change content type of all existing folders/subfolders to newly created content type?